# Failed to pass value to Method retrieve from another method error : java.util.HashSet cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, local-database

Here is the code mentioned i am trying to insert values in ArrayList and saving arrayList in Session Storage while key is different everytime.Now my target is to get selected value by passing "position" onclick of Spinner.Here are two mthods that are used to save values in SharePreferences i am getting error while trying to retrieve value from **getSpinnerSelectedValue**  method.

```
public static void setValuesInSession(Context c,String key,List<String> myArrayList)
{
    SharedPreferences sPrefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
    SharedPreferences.Editor sEdit=sPrefs.edit();
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    Log.i("myArrayList SharePrefereces",""+myArrayList +"::key::"+key);
    set.addAll(myArrayList);
    sEdit.putStringSet(key,set);
    sEdit.commit();
  }
public static  List<String> getValuesOfSession(Context c,String key)
{
    SharedPreferences sPrefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
    SharedPreferences.Editor sEdit=sPrefs.edit();
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    set = sPrefs.getStringSet(key,null);
    List<String> setList=new ArrayList<String>(set); 
    return setList;

}
public static void setSpinnerSelectedValue(Context c,String key,String value)
{SharedPreferences pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=pref.edit();
editor.putString(key,value);

}
public static String getSpinnerSelectedValue(Context c,String key)
{
      SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
     String val = sharedPrefs.getString(key,null); 
     return val;
}
```

**how i am using this code in Activity:**

```
SessionManager.setValuesInSession(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),menuFieldInstance.getFieldLabel().toString(),[0100,0200,0300,0400,0500]);
     siteSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
    View view, int position, long id) {


    Log.i("Spinner Selected Value", "" + position);
    List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayList = SessionManager.getValuesOfSession(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),menuFieldInstance.getFieldLabel());
    Log.i("arrayList  Values",""+arrayList);
    Log.i("arrayList ",""+arrayList.get(position).toString());
    SessionManager.setSpinnerSelectedValue(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),menuFieldInstance.getFieldLabel(),arrayList.get(position).toString());                             
    }
```

getting Error when trying to retrieve values from "**`getSpinnerSelectedValue`**"  mthod ?

**here is the error List:**

```
02-11 02:23:05.455: E/AndroidRuntime(23432): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-11 02:23:05.455: E/AndroidRuntime(23432): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashSet cannot be cast to java.lang.String
02-11 02:23:05.455: E/AndroidRuntime(23432):    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getString(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:205)
02-11 02:23:05.455: E/AndroidRuntime(23432):    at com.mrfs.android.surveyapp.util.SessionManager.getSpinnerSelectedValue(SessionManager.java:85)
02-11 02:23:05.455: E/AndroidRuntime(23432):    at com.mrfs.android.surveyapp.activities.fragments.SiteFragmentActivity$3.onClick(SiteFragmentActivity.java:513)
02-11 02:23:05.455: E/AndroidRuntime(23432):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
02-11 02:23:05.455: E/AndroidRuntime(23432):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
02-11 02:23:05.455: E/AndroidRuntime(23432):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-11 02:23:05.455: E/AndroidRuntime(23432):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-11 02:23:05.455: E/AndroidRuntime(23432):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-11 02:23:05.455: E/AndroidRuntime(23432):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
02-11 02:23:05.455: E/AndroidRuntime(23432):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 02:23:05.455: E/AndroidRuntime(23432):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-11 02:23:05.455: E/AndroidRuntime(23432):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
02-11 02:23:05.455: E/AndroidRuntime(23432):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
02-11 02:23:05.455: E/AndroidRuntime(23432):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**onClick of Button i am calling method :**

```
siteSaveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
     Log.i("Session Values",SessionManager.getSpinnerSelectedValue(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Police Authority"));

    }
```

Comment: sharedPrefs.getString(key,null) method return hashset but you are trying to set in string

Comment: i am not returning hashset i have converted hashset in arrayList  Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
  set = sPrefs.getStringSet(key,null);
  List<String> setList=new ArrayList<String>(set); 
  return setList;

Comment: i m talking abt getSpinnerSelectedValue method.Plz check

Comment: can u please do changes in code ?

Comment: i have not write editor.commit() in oode when trying to write there getting error

Comment: can someone please guide me here what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: can you please update your code so that we can from where **getSpinnerSelectedValue** method getting called?

Comment: @HamidShatu  PLEASE see the edit i have written code there

Comment: Using **Debug** try see what types of value is returning by **getSpinnerSelectedValue**. May be this method returning a value that is not **String** type.

Comment: can u pls help me how can i  know datattype of a variable ?

Comment: and have u seen one thing that i didnt  write editor.commit()   in setSelectedSpinnerValue()  when i m trying to write its also showing me error